# Android record display and camera simultaneously. Supportet devices? Different approach?

Tags: android, video, android-camera, mediarecorder, screen-capture

We have created an application to record display and camera simultaneously.
The application should be used to examine user behavior on mobile devices.
Unfortunately the App crashes when recording is started.

We assume that this happens because the mobile does not support multiple instances of MediaRecorder (Samsung Note 4).

Has anyone tested which devices support that?

Does anyone know a different approach to record both simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm developing the exact same thing.
In order to use several `MediaRecorder`, we used a service with its own process.

Here is an extract of our `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<!-- The screen recording has to happen in a separate process because it's not possible to
         use multiple MediaRecorder instances in the same process. And Android does not seem to
         like if it's tried to capture a camera in a separate process. -->
    <service
        android:name=".ScreenRecordingService"
        android:process=":screenrecorder" />

    <service android:name=".CameraRecordingService" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the information!
Unfortunately it still does not work.
What devices do you use for testing?

Comment: I used a Huawei p8 and a Nexus 5x